# C++ data storing

Tags: c++

I have to create a dictionary program. This program will save all the words on to one variable and the type, definition like wise to other variables which are coming in from a text file.

**The text file format**

```
 - word
 - meaning
 - type
 - blank line
```

**Example**

```
abacinate
To blind by a red-hot metal plate held before the eyes.
v

abacination
The act of abacinating.
n
```

the code that I have type is:

```
void Files::read() {
     Files d;
     int i = 0;

     ifstream out("dictionary2020.txt");

     string array[][4] { d.word,d.definition,d.type,d.blank };
     vector<string> words;

    do {
        array[i] [4];

        getline(out, d.word, '\n');
        getline(out, d.definition, '\n');
        getline(out, d.type, '\n');
        getline(out, d.blank, '\n');

        // string array[] [4] = { d.word,d.definition,d.type,d.blank };

        /*++i;
        for (int i{}; i != 3; ++i) 
            for (int j{}; j != 5; ++j)
                out >> array[i][j];*/
        cout << d.word << endl;
    } while (!out.eof());
    
    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) 
        cout <<"array"<< array[a] << endl;

    string search;
    ifstream inFile;
    string line;

    //inFile.open("dictionary2020.txt");

    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Enter word to search for: ";
    cin >> search;

    size_t pos;
    while (inFile.good()) {
           getline(inFile, line); // get line from file
           pos = line.find(search); // search
           if (pos != string::npos) {  // string::npos is returned if string is not found
               cout << "Found!";       
               break;
           }
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

How to put the data on to word, definition and type array and store that array on a vector or another array? The dictionary file has over 106,000 words then when a user enters a word he should be able to get the type and definition of the word.

Comment: Open your textbook and read the section about `std::map` and user-defined classes/structs.

Comment: a piece of thought.. what you would do with converted words, where word can be used a different part of speech? with homonyms and multiple meanings?

Comment: For what you want to achieve I would be using an avl tree with reverse indexing. Have a structure that holds the details of the word and insert the word as the key. Doing this correctly will have use o(logn) and is a much better way

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `std::map` data structure defined in header `map`.

Read the doc for std::map here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

A **map** is a data structure that can efficiently retrieve a *value* when prompted with a *key*.

In your case, the keys will be the words. The values with be objects from a custom class that holds the word, its type and its definition. The type can be an enum or an std::string.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Word
{
   public:
      enum Type { VERB, NOUN, ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, INTERJECTION, PREPOSITION, DETERMINER, CONJUNCTION, WHATEVER };

      std::string word;
      std::string definition;
      enum Type type;

      Word(std::string w, std::string d, std::string t) : word(w), definition(d)
      {
          // here transform std::string t into enum Type type
      }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::map<std::string, Word> dictionary;
    Word abacinate("abacinate", "To blind by a red-hot metal plate held before the eyes.", "v");
    dictionary["abacinate"] = abacinate;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you could make the answer better by providing overloads of `operator>>` and `operator<`.  The `operator<` would help with the map and sorting.

Comment: i tried the std::map function by it doesnt work for data thats coming in from a text file. it worked perfectly for me on a static data that is hard coded with the software but in my case i have a text file that has nearly 106,187 words and each of them have their own means and types. it is not possible to use 2d arrays to store the data and if so how do i go about doing it.

Comment: @stef like you said have tried maps but with it only two elements can be stored right or is there any other way to store 3 elements